# How to view list of all site collections url in share point 2003

Tags: 2003

I want to View all the Site Collections list in the SharePoint 2003,is there any way to view the list of sites and sub sites in SP2003

Comment: You are talking about two things, Site collections and Sites/subsites.
And, you're sure it's SP2003? Not SP2013? Please explain a bit more...

Answer (score 1):

To list all site collections, run the following command and you'll get site collection and owners:

```
stsadm -o enumsites -url http://webappname
```

Ref: [List of All SharePoint Sites (Site Directory not enough)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f19a3a9f-bfe2-4015-a549-56c2d3dc8a4d/list-of-all-sharepoint-sites-site-directory-not-enough?forum=sharepointadminlegacy)

---

To see subsites, do the following:

> View the list of immediate subsites for a site
>
> 1. On the site, click Site Settings.
> 2. On the Site Settings page, under Administration, click Manage sites and workspaces.

Ref: [Managing Sites and Subsites (Windows SharePoint Services 2.0)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288332(v=office.12).aspx)